# Correct flow for Stripe payout in a higher level view

Tags: stripe-payments, strip

I have a scenario in that I will create a payout flow (based on Stripe's APIs) for 2 participants. One is the platform owner, the other is the customers who use the platform service. The platform owner creates a service that allows his customers to register to his platform service, and to provide services to customers' end users (customer's customers). The payout flow then will transfer money from the platform owner's bank account to the customers (a list of customers who registers to platform owner's service) manually when the platform owner confirms to pay by pressing a payout button.

I've done some research, but I am still not sure about the correct steps for processing this payout flow. The doc I found so far is [1], which looks like the one that fits my scenario. So my first question - Is the doc[1] the right direction to work on?

If that's correct, a few more questions. In the step 2.5's `return_url`[2] section, the doc mentions to listen to the `account.updated` event. I create a webhook e.g. https://example.com/return and listening to that event. And the webhook can receive the `account.updated` event without a problem. However, in the section 2.4[3], after creating an account link, Stripe returns an url like `https://connect.stripe.com/setup/c/<random string>`, which asks user to fill in info including

- **BUSINESS DETAILS**
- **MANAGEMENT AND OWNERSHIP**

After clicking the submit button, if the return_url is configured to reuse the webhook i.e. https://example.com/return. The service will return following error

```
{"code":405,"message":"method GET is not allowed, but [POST] are"}
```

Otherwise redirecting result will return

```
{"code":404,... }
```

I understand it's because the webhook /return I setup listening to POST operation. If `return_url` should be handled in GET, what parameters will passed to that `return_url`. I search online, but I do not see any explanation. Any docs or code that may provide some related info? I appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

[1]. https://stripe.com/docs/connect/add-and-pay-out-guide

[2]. https://stripe.com/docs/connect/add-and-pay-out-guide?integration=with-code#return_url

[3]. https://stripe.com/docs/connect/add-and-pay-out-guide?integration=with-code#with-code-redirect-to-account-link

Comment: You're mixing up webhooks and return URL. The former is an endpoint you add for Stripe to send you updates about your account (or connected account) such as a new payment, a dispute, etc. The latter is where we redirect the person who is signed up for a connected account. Webhooks are POST requests, the return url is a GET request. I think this goes way beyond stackoverflow though and you should talk to Stripe's support team: https://support.stripe.com/contact/email

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @koopajah One more question. Generally what's the right way to handle return_url? I create an endpoint listening to GET method for return_url. However I notice the query string is empty. So I am confused. Does that mean when handling return_url, I only need to redirect the user to e.g. dashboard? Then it's done? Or in addition to redirecting the user to dashboard, at the same time  I have to use another webhook listening to `account.update` event (as described in the link https://stripe.com/docs/connect/add-and-pay-out-guide?integration=with-code#return_url)?

Comment: You control the return_url so you can put query params if you want and add a unique state/token id in it. But I recommend using cookies/session. You should know the person before sending them to Stripe and you should know who they are when they come back.

Comment: @koopajah That makes sense. Thank you again for your help!